# Прошу помочь добаить функцию.PHP

Tags: php, авторизация

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $login = (!empty($_POST['login'])) ? $_POST['login'] : false;
    $pass = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

    if ($login && $pass) {
            $password = md5(sha1(md5($pass)));

            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?s", $login);
            $queryNum = $db->numRows($query);
            $queryFetch = $db->fetch($query);


            if ($queryNum) {
                if ($password == $queryFetch['password']) {
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $queryFetch['id'];
                    header('Location: /tab.php');
                } else {
                    $error = 'Пароль не совпадает';
                }
            } else {
                $error = 'Такого логина нету';
            }

    } else {
        $error = 'Заполните данные';
    }
}


?>
```

Кому не сложно, помогите решить вопрос, возможно он глупый. Подкажите как исправить функцию     if ($queryNum), что бы при опрделеном логине и пароле заходил на одну страницу. Например в дб запись id="1" login = "petya" pass= "123" под этим заходил на tab.php а все остальные заходили tab2.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($password == $queryFetch['password']) {
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $queryFetch['id'];
    if ($_POST['login'] == 'YOUR_LOGIN' && $password == 'YOUR_PASSWORD') {
        header('Location: /tab.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: /tab2.php');
    }
} else {
    $error = 'Пароль не совпадает';
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]